# sammy.js : camel case urls

Tags: sammy.js

How can I force sammy.js to recognize a url `/Brief` to be the same as `/brief`?

```
this.get('/brief', function(context) {
    console.log("BRIEF");
});
```

I have my CMS setup to generate lower case urls, however if a user types in a url with a camel case format I get the error:

```
Tue Mar 19 2013 15:39:31 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Daylight Time)] body 404 Not Found get /Brief  Error {message: "404 Not Found get /Brief "}
```

The page still loads fine, but Sammy.js won't activate the module for that route.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a case insensitive regex expression to match any case of alpha characters:

```
this.get(/\/brief/i, function(context) {
    console.log("BRIEF");
});
```